# How to add data to array using button

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add data to ajax_data everytime I push add row button. Obviously the code works when it's not a function, but how to make it work as a function?

Fresh JS programmer.

```js
var ajax_data = [{
  Type: "Analog Input 0",
  Tag: "AI0",
  Description: "Description"
}, ]
var new_row = {
  Type: "Analog Input 2",
  Tag: "AI2",
  Description: "Description"
}

$("Add_row").click(function(ajax_data, new_row) {
  ajax_data.push(new_row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Add_row" name="button">Add row</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `but how to make it work as a function`? `.push` already is a function and you're writing your code in `function`

Comment: I *think* what OP means is that `ajax_data.push` says it's not a function....because the callback's parameter `ajax_data` shadows the outer `ajax_data` array.

Comment: Delete **ajax_data, new_row** from function params, and THIS code will work. But I suppose you’ll be using AJAX, and that may be different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `$("#Add_row").click` function you have `ajax_data` and `new_row` as argument names. Meanwhile you have your variables defined the same name outside as well. If you reference `ajax_data` and `new_row` inside the function, JavaScript will retrieve the arguments and not the variables defined outside. They are undefined because nothing was passed when the function was called. Remove them and it should work.

Also, I recommend [retiring the use of `var` in Javascript and use `let`/ `const`.](https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70)

```js
let ajax_data = [{
  Type: "Analog Input 0",
  Tag: "AI0",
  Description: "Description"
}, ]
let new_row = {
  Type: "Analog Input 2",
  Tag: "AI2",
  Description: "Description"
}

$("#Add_row").click(() => {
  ajax_data.push(new_row);
  console.log(ajax_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Add_row" name="button">Add row</button>
```